# i'm to to create an ending election page for a game i am making in html, however i am unable to get the if statements working or the input

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

how do i fix it?
this is my code:

```
`    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function search(){
                var choose = document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML;
                setInterval(() => { 
                    if(choose == 1){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    if(choose== 2){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    if(choose== 3){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    if(choose== 4){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    if(choose== 5){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    if(choose== 6){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    if(choose== 7){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    if(choose== 8){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    if(choose== 9){
                        window.location.href = "1:1:1.html"; 
                    };
                    
                }, 10);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="search()">
      <form>
        <label for="choice">enter 1-9 to travel to that ending</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="choice" name="choice" class="choice"><br>
      </form>
    </body>

</html>``
```

i have tried many different potential solutions, like textcontent, inner text and other things. however none of it seems to work. I am trying to make it so that when someone types a number from 1-9 in, it takes them to that specific ending. They currently all go to the same place but that will be fixed later on, as they currently don't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `.value` to get what was typed into the `<input>`.
2. Don't use a `setInterval`. Instead, add an event listener for the `"input"` event so you can check the value every time it changes.

```js
<form>
    <label for="choice">enter 1-9 to travel to that ending</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="choice" name="choice" class="choice"><br>
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("choice").addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    const choose = +this.value;
    // do something based on the value...
});
</script>
```